# Content tree search - add criterion

Tags: content-editor, content-search

This is using 8.1 Update 2. Going by this Sitecore doc - https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/content_authoring/searching/search_for_an_item - I'm looking at the last section, Add a criterion to a search from the content tree in the Content Editor. I've clicked on the type of item I want, and I click the default Name field to see the dropdown list of the fields in my selected type. I'm trying to click on one of these fields so I can search on it instead of Name, but it won't let me select any custom criteria.

I'm also trying to use the main body search in Content Editor to do the same thing. If I click on the top-level folder and click the Search icon in the main body, I get the Search[1] tab. I click the dropdown arrow and choose Search Filter, the Search by a Field Value. It adds a "custom" tag with a textbox to type, but whatever combo of "field name = field value" I try, it says it's invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the issue with the Content Tree search in a clean instance of 8.1.2, but I was not able to reproduce the issue with the Content Search in the Content Editor. For the first issue, I recommend that you file a Support Ticket.

For the second issue, first check to make sure that you don't have any errors in your logs. Next, make sure that you have the syntax for the search correct. The syntax should be as follows:

```
custom:fieldname|fieldvalue
```

Where `fieldname` is the name of the field that you are searching against and `fieldvalue` is the value in the field that you are searching for.

If you are still having issues with the Content Search, update your support ticket to also include details about the issue and also update this post with any errors from your logs, the exact criteria that you are searching for, what you've tried, etc.

Comment: Thanks, Zachary. I'm finding the field search in the "main" window isn't finding it either, so I've sent a ticket to support asking after it all.